# Want to click dropdown button using selenium webdriver code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click dropdown button using selenium webdriver code. HTML is as follows:

```html
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick ua-bo-select" style="width: 222px;">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="invContactList" title="" data-original-title="Nothing selected">
```

What will be the accurate code?

Please check the dropdown button which my application is using

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: I have used following code  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='invEmailAssocDiv']/div/div[2]/div/button")).click(); and getting following error  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command

Comment: @RashmiKakade can you provide some more info as follows: 1.Is it a normal dropdown or a Bootstrapped dropdown? 2. Can you provide a snapshot of the dropdown? 3.Provide some more of the HTML DOM.

Comment: It a bootstrapped dropdown. please find snapshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO3hs.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no 'a'Tag in this HTML. SO using Select will not work. Instead do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']")).Click();
```

Then Spy on the dropdown values and give another xpath or ID. It will work.

I think the xpath you have given is wrong.Try the above or below:

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@data-id='invContactList']")).Click();
```

Comment: I tried both the code lines but its giving me error as  "The method click() is undefined for the type List<WebElement>" Could you please share full code ?

Comment: my bad - Remove 's'  from findElements...It is just FindElement Will edit it.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooo much Freak Tester :) my code is working now.

Comment: Hi, yesterday i have tried above code lines and run code. It worked once and started getting facing same issue again there after org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException.  Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these below code using `xpath` locator.

**Explanation:** Use `data-id` attribute of `<button>` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@data-id='invContactList']")).Click();
```

> OR

**Explanation:** Use `data-original-title` attribute of `<button>` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-original-title='Nothing selected']")).Click();
```

> OR

**Explanation:** Use `data-toggle` attribute of `<button>` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']")).Click();
```

Comment: Have you try this code? Does my explanation of code helped you?

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.